# How do I catch 502 exceptions?

Tags: 6

While running the batch process, it takes more than 5 hours to complete; before that, it returns a 502 error. How do I handle it?

Answer (score 1):

*HTTP 502 Bad Gateway* is, as its name says, something that happened on your gateway, not on your server. Since the error is between you and your server, Drupal can't really know it happened unless, of course, you are talking about a job that connects to a remote server and the error happens between your site and that remote server. If so, you can either ask admins to fix gateways, or file a bugreports: one to service provider, and the other to the author of the module you are using.

Comment: i understood it happens because of the gateway error, if it happens i want to catch those errors and log the error type, name and time into database.

Comment: @Kumanan Is it situation from first or second paragraph? If from first - impossible. Your server cannot know your request never reached it. Can't distinguish things not sent at all from things lost in route on the receiving end. If from second paragraph - add more data to your question